# how to access Enum fields in playframework template

Tags: java, enums, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have an `Enum` which has certain fields ,which I need to access in my `play1.2.4` template

```
public Enum WORKER{
   FARMER,SMITH,GARDENER
}
```

Suppose I need to check if a 'person' variable in the template is a farmer,smith or gardener ,how can I do it?

```
#{if person.Type==WORKER.FARMER}
   ...do something...
#{/if}
```

Here I get

```
NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'FARMER' on null object.
```

So,the template doesn't know about the Enum WORKER.Since a new instance cannot be created for Enum ,how should I make the Enum available to the template?

Comment: What is `Status`? your enum is called `WORKER`

Comment: sorry..typo...Anyway,I figure it out..I was missing the package prefix

Comment: What about abstracting that behind a method? Ex. `worker.isFarmer()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the enum's absolute class name in the template.
E.g. if your enum `WORKER` is in the package `model.myenums`, the template code would look like this:

```
#{if person.Type == model.myenums.WORKER.FARMER}
   ...do something...
#{/if}
```